# R: replacing special character in multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I try to replace the german special character "ö" in a dataframe by "oe". The charcter occurs in multiple columns so I would like to be able to do this all in one by not having to specify individual columns.
Here is a small example of the data frame

```
data <- data.frame(a=c("aö","ab","ac"),b=c("bö","bb","ab"),c=c("öc","öb","acö"))
```

I tried :

```
data[data=="ö"]<-"oe"
```

but this did not work since I would need to work with regular expressions here. However when I try :

```
data[grepl("ö",data)]<-"oe"
```

I do not get what I want.
The dataframe at the end should look like:

```
> data
   a  b   c
1 aoe boe  oec
2 ab bb  oeb
3 ac ab acoe
>
```

The file is a csv import that I import by read.csv. However, there seems to be no option to change to fix this with the import statement.
How do I get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
data <- apply(data,2,function(x) gsub("ö",'oe',x))
```

Explanation:

Your `grepl` doesn't work because `grepl` just returns a boolean matrix (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) corresponding to the elements in your data frame for which the regex matches. What the assignment then does is replace not just the character you want replaced but the entire string. To replace *part* of a string, you need `sub` (if you want to replace just once in each string) or `gsub` (if you want all occurrences replaces). To apply that to every column you loop over the columns using `apply`.

Comment: Thank you! Also the explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return a data frame, you can use:

```
data.frame(lapply(data, gsub, pattern = "ö", replacement = "oe"))
```