# Changing multiple markup errors over multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I run stuck over a piece of coding that allows me to change multiple text markup errors, ie "Ã¯Â¿Â½nt" which should be "ent", or "Ã¯Â¿Â½de" which should be "ide", or "Ã¯n" which should be "in" (without quotation marks), over 47 columns in total.

A quick example of the dataframe

```
x <- data.frame("Name"(c("PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt", "PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt"),"Type"(c("Ã¯Â¿Â½de", "Ã¯Â¿Â½de"),"Role"(c("Ã¯n", "Ã¯n")))))
$x
Name         Type      Role
PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt  Ã¯Â¿Â½de  Ã¯n
PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt  Ã¯Â¿Â½de  Ã¯n
```

(Not sure if code is correct, but you get the meaning of how my dataframe looks like).

Now, what I tried from other posted solutions, especially from: [the one posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656676/r-replacing-special-character-in-multiple-columns-of-a-data-frame) is that I ended up with quite some line of code, an excerpt:

```
x <- data.frame(lapply(x, function(y){ gsub("Ã¯Â¿Â½ne", "ine", y)}))
```

So, for every text markup error there is a line of code like above, that fixes the markup error. However, using the lapply/apply family it changes my original classes to factors. And using the stringr package, I can not get this done since it keeps putting it in a single vector, an excerpt

```
x <- str_replace(string = x, pattern="Ã¯Â¿Â½nt", replacement = "ent")
```

So my question here is: is there another way to replace multiple strings over multiple columns, meanwhile maintaining the original dataframe classes?

### EDIT

I edited slightly the code from Calum You to:

```
mutate_at(.vars = vars(everything()),
                   .funs = ~ str_replace_all(., pattern = "Ã¯Â¿Â½nt", replacement = "")) %>%
```

Such that it replaces all instances within a row, instead of the first. 
Next, by using the snippet below before the functions of mutate_at, the code now iterates only over character vectors instead of all vectors, i.e. numeric/factor/date etc.

```
df2 <- df1[, sapply(df1, class) == 'character'] %>%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to apply your replace function to every column, because the markup errors can be in any column? Try this approach, which uses `mutate_at` to apply your function to as many columns as you like (here to all of them)

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  Name = c("PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt", "PatÃ¯Â¿Â½nt"),
  Type = c("Ã¯Â¿Â½de", "Ã¯Â¿Â½de"),
  Role = c("Ã¯n", "Ã¯n")
)

df %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(everything()),
    .funs = ~ str_replace(., pattern = "Ã¯Â¿Â½nt", replacement = "ent")
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(everything()),
    .funs = ~ str_replace(., pattern = "Ã¯Â¿Â½de", replacement = "ide")
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(everything()),
    .funs = ~ str_replace(., pattern = "Ã¯n", replacement = "in")
  )
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name   Type  Role 
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 Patent ide   in   
2 Patent ide   in
```

Comment: Thank you for your posted solution. It works. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can edit the vars() function to be applied to character variables only, skipping the numerical ones in my data frame.